# About the an unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am writing a C# windows forms program. When I want to login in the windows form, I get an error that says:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Invalid object name 'Login'.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

What should I do? Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class LOGIN : Form
    {
        public LOGIN()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\kenlui\Documents\LoginDate.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) from Login where Username ='" + textBox1.Text + "' and Password = '" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            {
                this.Hide();
                main ss = new main();
                ss.Show();


            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Check Username and Password");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your DB. Is there a `Login` table?

Comment: You did not open the connection?

Comment: Add you own exception handler (try/catch) around the new SQLConnection() statement.  If an exception occurs then do not run the rest of the code.

Comment: You probably need to preface Login with the database/schema name

Comment: The term `Login` is often a reserved word in SQL Servers (used in some statements). Have you tried escaping the table name? For example like this when using an MS SQL Server: `[Login]`

Answer (score 2):

Either `dbo.Login` table does not exist OR it is associated with a different schema. When you create your tables and database objects you should prefix them with `dbo.` unless you know what schemas are and how to use them.

Some additional issues I find with your code:

- You should never use string concatenation to create a sql statement. This leaves your code vulnerable to sql injection attacks and also syntax error (if the user name or password contained a `'` for example.). Use parameterized sql instead.
- Never store passwords in plain text. Use a hashing library and create a secure 1 way hash and persist that. When logging in create a hash from the presented password in the UI and compare that to the value in the database.
- Your code never closes the database connection. To ensure it is always closed after you are done with it wrap it in a `using` block to ensure it is closed and disposed, this will help even if an exception is thrown.

Code with some corrections.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\kenlui\Documents\LoginDate.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;"))
    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) from Login where Username = @userName and Password = @password", con))
    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
    {
        sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userName", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = textBox1.Text });
        // this should be a hash of the password, not the plain text value
        sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = textBox2.Text });

        sda.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {
            this.Hide();
            main ss = new main();
            ss.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Check Username and Password");
        }
    }
}
```

Finally instead of using a SqlDataAdapter consider using SqlCommand with ExecuteScalar instead.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\kenlui\Documents\LoginDate.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;"))
    using (SqlCommand sda = new SqlCommand("Select 1 from Login where Username = @userName and Password = @password", con))
    {
        sda.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userName", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = textBox1.Text });
        // this should be a hash of the password, not the plain text value
        sda.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = textBox2.Text });
        var result = sda.ExecuteScalar();

        if (result != null && 1 == (int)result)
        {
            this.Hide();
            main ss = new main();
            ss.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Check Username and Password");
        }
    }
}
```